# how to delete columns with same values in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

How is it possible to delete all the columns that have the same values in a `NumPy` array?

For example if I have this matrix:

```
[0 1 2 3 1]  
[0 2 2 1 0]  
[0 4 2 3 4]  
[0 1 2 3 4]  
[0 1 2 4 5]
```

I want to get a new matrix that looks like this:

```
[1 3 1]  
[2 1 0]  
[4 3 4]  
[1 3 4]  
[1 4 5]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can compare the array with the shifted version of itself, if all pairs are equal for a column, then the column contains only one unique value, which can be removed with boolean indexing:

```
a[:, ~np.all(a[1:] == a[:-1], axis=0)]

#array([[1, 3, 1],
#       [2, 1, 0],
#       [4, 3, 4],
#       [1, 3, 4],
#       [1, 4, 5]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

```python
import numpy
a = numpy.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 1],
                 [0, 2, 2, 1, 0],
                 [0, 4, 2, 3, 4],
                 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                 [0, 1, 2, 4, 5]])
```

then

```python
b = a == a[0,:]   # compares first row with all others using broadcasting
# b: array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#           [ True, False,  True, False, False],
#           [ True, False,  True,  True, False],
#           [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
#           [ True,  True,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

using `all` along the rows acts as a row-wise `and` operation (thanks Divakar!):

```python
c = b.all(axis=0)
# c: array([ True, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

which you can use for boolean indexing

```python
a[:, ~c]
Out: 
array([[1, 3, 1],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [4, 3, 4],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [1, 4, 5]])
```

---

As an ugly oneliner:

```python
a[:, ~(a == a[0,:]).all(0)]
```

Comment: Good idea to start with. But, why not simply do : `~b.all(0)` and use that to mask out columns? Should be more performant and also shorter than prod-reduce and type conversion.

Comment: @Divakar thanks, that's actually the command I was looking for :D